# AWS Lambda Serverless deploy asking for AWS provider credentials even after adding the credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy my lambda function using the below command

`serverless deploy`

But I get this error

ServerlessError: AWS provider credentials not found.

But I have configured AWS credentials using the below command

`serverless config credentials --provider aws --key AKINA4KOZEU44A --secret X0DGlLin/Gn89GPIAOLr8gnwZWAWLCv+ --profile serverless-admin`

and still getting the same error.

Comment: Add provider in serverless file and check whether the .aws/credentials file you have something like this, 
Add provider in serverless file and check whether the .aws/credentials file you have something like this, 
`[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding profile in serverless.yml

`provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  profile: serverless-admin`